# java.lang.SecurityException with No Details

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-securityexception

I searched around for this but couldn't find a solution to my case. I just updated my app to target Android API 25. Thus I had to update permission handling. My app requires the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have added all the code to check/request permissions and tested it on two different phones. However a few users are getting this crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:318)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1693)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1646)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerNative.java:4912)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:6043)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:2474)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:1521)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:520)
  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground (CursorLoader.java:64)
  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground (CursorLoader.java:56)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:304)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

As you can see I'm getting a security exception with no details. Also the stack trace shows that it doesn't originate from my code at all.

Can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this? Am I reading the stack trace wrong?

EDIT: The problem must originate from trying to build a list of user emails from contacts. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}
```

Comment: add more details to question, stack trace seems incomplete

Comment: Do you use `CursorLoader` in your app?

Comment: My code is using `CursorLoader` to populate user emails from contacts.

Comment: This is the entire stack trace from Google Play Console. I can't reproduce it when debugging the two Android phones I have.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was happening. In my code there was a more obscure place calling this:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

The solution was to do normal permission checks before getting user contact data.

It turns out that Google Play Console will not show the security exception details in it's stack trace. You can only see the actual required permission in debug mode.

Comment: What do you meant by "to do normal permission checks". Do you have the code example ?